# How to know whether the window is maximized or minimised in extjs?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, extjs, extjs3

Does any one know how to check whether the form is maximised or minimised in IE8.

Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved by using this code:

```
var S = this.tabpanelFormation.getPosition();
    if (Ext.isIE8 && S[0] == 751) {
            this.tabpanelFormation.setPagePosition(749,370,true);
            this.tabpanelFormation.setHeight(230);
            this.tabpanelFormation.setWidth(350);
    }
```

If its maximised then S[0] = 751. By this we can find whet

Answer (score 0):

Take a scan through their docs here:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api

you can use window.screen.width and window.screen.height to get the dimensions of the screen being used.

then you can use getPosition() and make sure that it is at 0,0 
and use getHeight() and getWidth() and make sure that they match the screen sizes.

Comment: Hi @Caleb i am using Ext.TabPanel